# query on manyToMany field with related_name

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

my models:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    pass

class CourseRun(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='course_runs')

class Category(models.Model):
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='category_set')
```

for some reason I was forced to add many2many in Category model instead of Course model

---

my question:
how can I search on CourseRun by category id

somethings like this:

```
CourseRun.objects.filter(course__category__in=[1, 2])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set the [**`related_query_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name), then that is the name you should use when filtering in reverse. If you set the [**`related_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), and not a `related_query_name`, then Django will use the `related_name` for the `related_query_name` as well. If you do not set a `related_name` and `related_query_name`, then `related_name` will default to `modelname_set` (so here `category_set`) and `related_query_name` to `modelname` (so here `category`).

## Option 1: use the `related_name`

So you can filter with the `related_name` in your query:

```
CourseRun.objects.filter(course__category_set__in=[1, 2])
```

## Option 2: set a `related_query_name`

Another option is to set the `related_query_name` to something else, for example `'category'`:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(
        Course,
        related_name='category_set',
        related_query_name='category'
    )
```

Then you can filter with:

```
CourseRun.objects.filter(course__category__in=[1, 2])
```

Comment: Note if you don't set either, then the `related_name` defaults to `category_set` (`set` appended to lowercase model name) and the `related_query_name` defaults to `category` (lowercase model name)

Comment: @dirkgroten: yes. I've added that to the answer.