# Django: foreign key (many-to-many) show value

Tags: django, logging, foreign-keys

I have the following simple django model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
"""
An account is for a team of users, or a single customer
"""
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
admins = models.ManyToManyField('AccountUser', related_name='+', blank=True)
metadata = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

@property
def customers(self):
    """Accounts linked to this account"""
    return self.linked_accounts.linked_accounts.all()
```

I am trying to loop through the account table and show the account records in a view:

```
queryset_account = Account.objects.all()

for account in queryset_account:
    logger.warning(account.name)
    logger.warning(account.admins)
```

the account name is showing but the foreign key admins is returning none. How can I display the content of admins?

**UPDATE**

I have modified the code to incorporate Shreeyansh's suggestion:

```
for account in queryset_account:
    logger.warning('account name: %s', account.name)
    for admin in account.admins.all():
        logger.warning('admin: %s', admin)
```

but still not getting values for admins although all my account have them

Comment: it's because of related name you set. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60299460/12009358

Comment: Show `AccountUser` model also check again if it has records.

Answer (score 0):

As `admins` is manytomany field it will represent a list of objects and as per your model definition it may be blank as well. so in order to read the values from admins you need to iterate over the list.

```
print([admin for admin in account.admins.all()])
```

Comment: Hi Shreeyansh, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I have modified the code to include your suggestion but I get still an empty list when I know that there are admins associate to my accounts (please see update)